# Refactoring god-class leads to feature envy

Tags: architecture, refactoring, anti-patterns

I'm trying to refactor a 2.5KLOC god-class (with about 68 data members and 62 member functions) that performs a wide variety of text formatting and layout operations. After a careful analysis based on:

1. Which member function reference which data members and,
2. The logical formatting sub-tasks

I've partitioned the data members and members functions into 9 classes. The problem now is that most of these smaller classes are repeatedly reaching for data held by other classes (classic feature envy). What sort of refactoring would be advisable in this situation?

It probably doesn't matter bit if it does, I'm programming in C++.

Comment: We can't really help you with such generic problem. Maybe your initial refactoring was wrong?

Comment: Probably. Maybe a god-class is the lesser or two evils.

Comment: I wouldn't say that. Maybe there is different design that is not a god class and that doesn't have feature envy. But we can't tell you what design that is, as we have zero information about the code you are working with.

Comment: I realize the question is a bit generic without some code but you really don't want to see 2.5KLOC class with 68 data members and 62 member functions. Conceptually if some class X held the commonly used data, other classes would end up referencing X. Alternatively the member functions that reference X could be moved to X, but this would be the beginnings of another god-class.

Comment: What do you mean with "commonly used data"? Also, is this reference read/write or read-only? That is quite a big differenence. And two smaller god-classes is IMO better than single big god-class. Not perfect, but better. And it could be good mid-point for additional refactoring.

Comment: Can you move "envious" functions to the appropriate classes, or extract parts of functions (as new functions) and move those? Then repeat until you've minimized feature envy? Not sure if refactoring tools that support this are available for C++, but you can always do it manually (although that's somewhat tedious and error prone).

Comment: @Euphoric I meant to say data that's commonly 'cross-referenced'. I'll try to identify the worst 'culprits'.

Comment: We would need at least a diagram of the said 9 classes and their dependencies. And if possible the name of each methods, hoping they're clear enough for us to understand what their purpose are.

Comment: Is it possible the key problem in your refactory is that classes have to *reach for data* instead of the (usually, hard to tell without eeing actual code) more sane *been told to do something with data*, i.e. a possible violation of the 'tell don't ask' principle? Imo just splitting up one class into 9 others but without changing much about the control flow won't be much better in the end.

Comment: Your problem is too vague to write a proper answer, but I can tell you that you should evaluate each method (yes one by one) and determine what *direct* dependencies they have.  Look for very common groupings, like 50 of 60 methods require classes A, B, and C.  In that case, you're probably looking at a good candidate for a class that acts like a facade for A, B, and C for the things you need for it to do.  Still, I don't envy you.  God classes don't become that way because they're easy to refactor.

Comment: Check to see if some of those function calls are redundant - like if a value is being calculated again, when it could have been stored to a class's public variable when it was first calculated. Unnecessary re-calculations are common in god classes because it avoids 'temporary' variables that shouldn't be temporary.

Comment: It would be helpful, so people can get a context for making suggestions, if you listed the names of the 68 data members and 62 member functions (i.e. the header of the god class). Additionally, a sample output or a screenshot of the expected output may also be useful.

Comment: I see the question has been put on hold as its too broad. I can understand that. Its going to be hard to provide detailed information without violating my company's IP. I've already received a lot of excellent advise which I will consider carefully. I hope to later edit my question to feedback my findings.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that could be going on that have different solutions depending on the data that's being cross referenced and how its used in each class.

1. You need a better Data object to pass to each new object that does contain all the information, if these are primitive values that other objects don't need to manipulate to be usable.
2. You need a common object to inherit from that handles common values, this would also be good only for read only references.
3. You have a poor abstraction and classes need to be modeled differently so all the needed data is in the same object.
4. You have business logic or objects that aren't being properly isolated.